# tons of problem, Fill_in_dev failed, black screen

Tags: 12.04, boot, nvidia

I'm new to this (linux world)

My friends recommended me to install ubuntu to start because it is basic and popular. lol.

I have this problem;

```
Disabling IRQ #10
Disabling IRQ #10
10 years later..
[drm:drm_pci_agp_init] Error. Cannot initialize the agpgart module. 
DRM: Fill_in_dev failed.
```

Then black screen.

Packard Bell Easynote TS11HR
Intel Core i5-2410M
4GB DDR3
Nvidia GT520M 512mb ram
HDD 640gb but i have windows too

Ubuntu version 13.10 (12.04 kernel panic error, mount root btw, another story)

I install this SO with noapi, nolapi, acpi=off and nomodereset, because it was the only way. black screen when select live and install, bootable options.

I try added those parameters in `sudo nano etc/default/grub`, but no results.

Can anyone help me? Or tell how can uninstall without affecting windows.

Sorry for bad english, i speak spanish.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your OS (Ubuntu 13.10) has been badly modified and resulted in kernel panic. When i experience the same thing as yours, I reinstall it again using my liveUSB and my extracted .iso in it. Did you install Ubuntu via wubi? else you can just delete it into the Windows directory.